# Google assistant SDK custom commands

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Currently following hot word example, I create custom commands like turn screen on/off, how do I disable voice response "sorry I can't help you"

Comment: how are you creating custom commands?

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways do it.follow this link and details [google assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/next-steps)

1 - if your using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/library/hotword.py) method/project creation and run it. then you can parse the request/query in event.args['text'] based on which you can perform activity local without sending it to google assistant. problems: google will response with some voice message parallel.

2 - use IFTTT, pretty simple to work with. basic use with webhooks takes little time though. [this link](https://www.hackster.io/phpoc_man/google-home-control-diy-devices-3be448) is useful and use ngrok for local webhook url

3 - use API.AI this is for advanced projects where you depend on google to assist with questions recognization and response with your answers from webhooks. it's not straight forward to work with, the details and tutorials that are given are with google cloud functions which works only with node.js as of now. if your python programmer or any other languages google has examples in [github](https://github.com/api-ai/fulfillment-webhook-translate-python) which are again not stright forward, I guess.